# Converting List to MutableList Kotlin gives error

Tags: kotlin

Trying to convert a List to mutableList

I did this `que.add(path.toMutableList() + mutableListOf(movement))`

`error: type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is List<Pair<Int, Int>> but MutableList<Pair<Int, Int>>! was expected que.add(path.toMutableList() + mutableListOf(movement))`

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the List? It doesn't look like a conversion issue, but a nullability issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plus operator is defined as an extension on `Collection<T>` and returns a `List<T>`. It doesn't matter if the operands are two mutable lists.

From the error message it seems that `que.add` expects a `MutableList`, not a `List`.

You can try something like this:

```
que.add(path.toMutableList().apply { add(movement) })
```